# Is it possible to delete a comment without reduction in reputation

Tags: discussion, reputation, comments

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How does “Reputation” work?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7237/how-does-reputation-work)

Suppose I want to answer a question but I have commented the answer to someones post. So if I delete the comment will it deduct my reputation also?

Comment: I suppose you mean [this comment of yours](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9698158/created-json-dynamically-but-how-to-prevent-from-ampersand-and-backslash#comment12327202_9698158)? If you think it answers the question then you can go ahead and post it as new answer instead, deleting the existing comment.

Answer (score 7):

No, comments don't have any impact on reputation.  You don't gain reputation when they're upvoted and you don't lose any when they're deleted.

Answer (score 6):

As comments don't earn you reputation, deleting them can't take any away.

The only thing that *might* happen is if another user decides that your answer was really a comment after all and decided to down vote it.